# Manually data input to a Power Query Table in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, crm

I'm working in a workbook for a store, which will be used to keep a record of client information and purchases.

I created a table object in Excel - say TBL_CLIENTS - to keep client attributes like name, address, city etc.

Then I created a query on TBL_CLIENTS to make a simple selection of some of its columns. After that I extended the resulting table - say TBL_ITEMS - to include columns for each of the itens in the store inventory. **At the intersection of a client (row) and item (column) I would manually input the price at which the client is buying the item.**

**What's the problem here:** if I refresh the query (after excluding clients from TBL_CLIENTS, for example), this will change the rows for each client in TBL_ITEMS, which makes me lose track of which client bought a item and at what price.

Is there a way to keep togheter the clients and the prices I manually input?

Many thanks!